# check if jQuery UI is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Testing if jQueryUI has loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260250/testing-if-jqueryui-has-loaded)

How to check if the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) extension library to jQuery is loaded on the page?

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260250/testing-if-jqueryui-has-loaded

Comment: wow, the search functionality for stackoverflow is so bad..I was really looking around before posting this and was amazed no one asked this before. 10x.

Comment: I would delete this question if I could...no need for copies.

Comment: alert($.ui.version) ;

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
if (typeof jQuery.ui !== 'undefined') ...
```

Should work.

See also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260250/testing-if-jqueryui-has-loaded).

Comment: @vsync: I [stronly disagree](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrXqR/) (play with checkbox for jQuery UI checkbox on left and hit "Run")

Comment: (typeof jQuery.ui === 'function') cuts out any ambiguity.

Comment: I agree with @vsync. If jQuery AND UI both aren't loaded, there's a false positive here. **That answer**, even if accepted/upvoted 28 times since 6 years, **is wrong**.  **The correct type to expect from `typeof(jQuery.ui)` is `object`**. A property like `tabs` is a `function`. If UI isn't loaded, `typeof(jQuery.ui.tabs)` will throw an error about undefined property. **So the best test is** `if(typeof(jQuery.ui) == "object") { if(typeof(jQuery.ui.tabs) == "function"){ console.log("jQuery-UI loaded")}}`. -- NOTICE that the need for a nested if condition is to avoid the undefined property error.

Answer (score 35):

Can check:

```
$.ui
```

Or get the version:

```
$.ui.version
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you put any code that calls it in $(document).ready(). At that point, everything should be loaded on the page.

Comment: I use scripts at bottom, always (before closing BODY tag). also, I want to know if the UI script is available on the page or not, as it's an unknown factor

Comment: Just because jQuery is loaded doesn't mean jQuery UI did (for example, resource could not be found, trouble loading, etc.)