# How to check if jQuery UI Position is loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position

jQuery has [a native `.position()` function](http://api.jquery.com/position/) right out of the box which gets positioning values of an element relative to its location on the page.

jQuery UI [extends that same function](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) to allow modification of positioning of elements.

**How do I check if the jQuery UI version of `.position()` is loaded in a page?**

Sadly, it isn't just a matter of [checking whether jQuery UI is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8052913/304588) on a page or not, since the `.position()` plugin extension is *not* part of the jQuery UI Core libraries, which means someone somewhere will have a jQuery UI framework loaded *without* the `.position()` plugin, and the linked jQuery UI check will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woops, wait; I think I found it.

Pages with jQuery UI loaded will indeed have `jQuery.ui` initialized (which will do fine for jQuery UI checks), but those with the `.position()` plugin baked in as well will have `jQuery.ui.position` initialized as well.

Figures that I find the answer 5 minutes after asking on SO. :-/

Answer (score 2):

The major difference is between the number of arguments in the function definition. The standard jQuery library has 0; jQuery UI has 1. If you can tell how many arguments are in the function definition, you can tell which library's function is present.

Fortunately, this is easy to do. A function's `length` property tells you how many arguments were in the function definition. So if `$.fn.position.length` is `0`, the function is that of the standard jQuery library; if it is `1` it is the jQuery UI library.

So:

```
if ($.fn.position.length === 1) {
    // jQuery UI position method loaded
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, and TIL about `(function).length` in Javascript. I found another way, and I kind of prefer that over this (a bit because it's more readable for me), but I'll wait just in case somebody throws a fit about my solution about compatibility or whatnot. :D Much appreciated! +1

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan No, your way is much better!