# jQuery UI dialog issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to create jquery dialog, but there is no use :(
here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    createDialog();

});
function createDialog() {

    $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");
    $("#dialog-form").dialog(
            {
                autoOpen : false,
                height : 475,
                width : 350,
                modal : true,
                buttons : {
                    "submit" : function() {

                        var bValid = true;
                        allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                        postText();
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    cancel : function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close : function() {
                    allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
                }
            });

    $(".add-org").click(function() {

            $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    });
}
```

here is html code:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/styles/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css"/>"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery-1.7.js'/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js'/>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/resources/js/myScript.js'/>"></script>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-org">New </a>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Add New ">
    <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
    <form>
    ..................
    </form>
</div>
```

and firebug says:

> TypeError: $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog is not a function
>
> $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

and on my page I see all the fields from the form.
so what is my problem?

Comment: Do you have that inside document ready?

Comment: does your js file "jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" include the jquery dialog plugin?

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: see updates, @allentranks, used search in jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js file, - yes, it includes

Comment: does it work if you comment this line $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy"); ?

Comment: nope, it argues with the lines ` close : function() ` and `cancel : function()`

Comment: @allentranks I suspect it would, since that line is wrong (see my answer).

Comment: @Helgus that's probably just a case of fixing your indentation and parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/kEZkh/

Not sure if your source path are correct please include following scripts.

rest please feel free to play around with demo & hope it helps the cause `:)`

**scripts**

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">


      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css">

      <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**code**

```
$("#forgot").click(function(e){ 
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#dialog-form").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 255,
            width: 300,
            buttons: {
                "Retrieve": function() {
                    document.forms["forgotform"].submit();
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
});
​
```

Comment: added including files from your list and it helped

Comment: why add jquery ui twice?

Answer (score 2):

Check in Firebug/DevTools if the script file was loaded successfully. If it is, type this into the console (Firebug, DevTools) or better, put that line where your other code is executed:

```
console.debug(jQuery.ui)
```

[If it shows `undefined`, then jQuery UI was not loaded (yet).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260250/testing-if-jqueryui-has-loaded) Check if your code runs before everything was loaded, put it inside jQuery's [`$(document).ready();`](http://jqapi.com/#p=ready). If it is an object, inspect it and check for the `dialog` property.

If you configured a custom build on [jqueryui.com](http://jqueryui.com), doublecheck if you included the dialog widget.

Comment: I guess that means that either the jQuery UI file is not loaded at all or your code runs before it is loaded and evaluated. 1: Check the network tab in the developer tools, you should see the request for that file. 2: Your code is in `myScript.js` and you definitely load that after jQuery UI?

Answer (score 0):

The `destroy` call should be on the same element as you already used when you created the dialog, not the `.ui-dialog` container that gets wrapped around your content:

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog('destroy');
```

Since your current code is throwing an exception, the subsequent lines which are supposed to create the dialog never get called.

If you want to destroy *every* dialog that might already be open, jQuery UI handily puts a `.ui-dialog-content` class on each content div:

```
$('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('destroy');
```