# jQuery resizable is not working inside of Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I created a dynamically resizable div as can be seen in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/18k3umpp/3/), but when I tried to put this code into my AngularJS project it doesn't work. NOTE: I have added the jQuery UI CSS. The only error message I receive is when I resize the page, here's what it says

> `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).resizable is not a function` [line 79 in controller].

## Controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('oct').controller('Analysis', ['$scope', '$log', 'OctSettings', function($scope, $log, OctSettings) {
    var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    console.log(inputs);

    $scope.changeView = function() {

        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (!inputs[i].checked) {
                if (tds[i].style.display !== 'none') tds[i].style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                if (tds[i].style.display === 'none') tds[i].style.display = '';
            }
        }

        if (!inputs[0].checked && !inputs[1].checked) rows[0].style.display = 'none';
        else rows[0].style.display = '';

        if (!inputs[2].checked) rows[1].style.display = 'none';
        else rows[1].style.display = '';

        disableChecksIfNeeded();

    };

    var disableChecksIfNeeded = function(num) {
        if (countChecks() > 1) {
            enableCheck('all');
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if (inputs[i].checked) inputs[i].disabled=true;
            }
        }
    };

    var disableCheck = function(num) {
        inputs[num].disabled = true;
    };

    var enableCheck = function(num) {
        if (num === 'all') {
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                inputs[0].disabled=false;
            }
        } else {
            inputs[num].disabled = false;
        }
    };

    var countChecks = function() {
        var count = 0;
        var index = -1;

        console.log(inputs.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].checked) count++;
        }
        return count;
    };

    $scope.changeView();



    $(window).on('load resize', function() {
        console.log('hi');
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var v1Width = $('#v1').width();


        $('#v1').resizable({
            minWidth: 50,
            maxWidth: windowWidth - 80,
            maxHeight: windowHeight * (0.83),
            handles: 'e, s'
        }).on('resize', function() {

            if (v1Width === $('#v1').width()) {
                $('#v2').height(0);
            }
            v1Width = $('#v1').width();
        });

        $('#v2').resizable({
            maxHeight: windowHeight * (0.83),
            handles: 's'
        }).on('resize', function() {
            $('#v1').height(0);
        });

    });

}]);
```

## View

```
<section class="analysis" ng-controller="Analysis">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="v1">View 1</td>

      <td id="v2">View 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">View 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="views-container">
    <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" ng-click="changeView()">
    View 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" ng-click="changeView()">
    View 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" ng-click="changeView()">
    View 3</label>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Are you sure your jquery-ui library files are visible to this file??

Comment: They should be, any idea on how I can check to be sure?

Comment: Console log this `Jquery.ui` to see if it loaded, like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260250/testing-if-jqueryui-has-loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason that I can think of is that, maybe the jquery-ui library is not visible to that file. First thing you might want to do is keep a line like this:

```
console.log(Jquery.ui);
```

And see if the ui library is loaded or not. If it is not, you need to find a way to make it visible to the Controller. For that, one solution might be to add the Library to your `index.html` or the specific view file that you want the jquery-ui to work on.

Another reason that I can come up with is, there might be incompatibility with the jquery and jquery-ui libraries. If you are using a the latest version of the jquery-ui, then it should be working with jquery 1.7 and above

Hope this helps.

Comment: yep I thought I only needed jquery forgot about jquery ui js file